# delaying moldy bread

Tags: storage-method, bread, mold

I always keep bread around, home-made or otherwise.  Is there a way to keep it from molding, or at least delay the process?

I've tried the fridge with some success (extra day or two), but I don't like my bread that cold to eat.

I've tried zip-top bags with no success (seems to mold faster).

Bread-box didn't seem to make any difference in time.

Thanks

Comment: related (if you're making your own, but some answers mention storage) : [Is there anything I can add to homemage bread to preserve it](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7804/is-there-anything-i-can-add-to-homemade-bread-to-preserve-it)

Comment: See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/61/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-storing-bread-in-various-locations (almost a dupe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My family eats a lot of bread. I bake six loaves at a time once or twice a week.

We freeze in plastic shopping bags all but two of them. When one loaf is eaten it is replaced from the freezer and the new loaf is allowed to thaw at room temperature.

Freezing is the only way I've found to reliably keep homemade bread for any length of time. Around here bread will mold within 3 or 4 days. I have had bread that was frozen for a month with no ill effect.

Comment: I find frozen bread alright for toast, but can't stand it defrosted, as with most freezing it affects the texture - the crumb alters.  With wholemeal (brown) bread it is not so bad, but with a soft white loaf the difference is significant.

Comment: @Orbling - I routinely thaw homemade sandwich breach (part wheat or white), French bread, and other rustic breads.  I don't have the problem you describe.  I freeze them wrapped in foil, always sliced for sandwich bread but both ways for others.

Comment: @justkt: Most people I know do so, my parents included - I've just never liked the result.  Mind you, I never eat commercial sliced bread either.  French bread was always fine, used to freeze that long ago.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [Bread Bags](http://www.asseenontv.com/prod-pages/deb_mey_bre_bag_ontv.html) (variation on [Green Bags](https://www.asseenontv.com/offers_on_demand/deb_m_gbags_ood_ontv.html), not sure which came first) with some reasonable success.  I'm sure there are other brands and sites to buy them from.  I normally just grab them at the grocery store/BB&B.  I only remember the details from the green bags, but they have lining that absorbs chemicals that are released by vegetables to slow down decay. I assume the bread bags use something similar, helping to control humidity as well.

We also slice then freeze bread, getting out slices as needed, throwing them in toaster to reheat.

Comment: I slice and freeze.  Sometimes I also freeze a whole loaf in foil and then thaw it in a warm oven.  It's the only foolproof way to keep bread fresh-ish.

Answer (score 0):

You can always let it dry out / go stale by keeping it in a paper bag, or something that'll allow moisture to escape ... the paper bag will slow down the process, but not stop it entirely.

Then, when it goes bad, it can at least be used for [croutons, french toast, etc.](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5279/uses-for-stale-bread), or even [resuscitated in the oven](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5592/is-there-a-way-to-bring-a-loaf-of-bread-thats-gone-dry-back-to-life).